# How do I call Ansible Tower REST API endpoint to launch job_template for a job_template id?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-tower, ansible-api

I have Ansible Tower API version: 3.7.0 and Ansible version: 2.9.13.

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.7.0/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates/Job_Templates_job_templates_launch_create) (attached image for reference) says that it supports a `POST` to `api/v2/job_templates/id/launch/` in order to launch job template.

However, when I call to the `POST` mentioned above I am getting the same response as I get via `GET` request to `job_templates` endpoint.

Expectation:

I want `POST` to `api/v2/job_templates/id/launch/` return HTTP 201 status code and execute the job.

Actual:

I see 200 HTTP status code containing the response body same as `GET` `api/v2/job_templates/id/launch` and without the `job_template` being executed.

[image]

Also notice that the GET on browser for Get api/v2/job_templates/id/ does not include the POST as an allowed method.
[image]

Comment: Since almost all debugging information is missing and the issue is not reproducible, can you provide information on: How do you construct the REST API calls? What is full JSON response of your call?

Comment: I was using the Postman to call the job_template launch endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your information provided I've performed a test under RHEL 7.9, Ansible Tower 3.7.3, Ansible v2.9.27.

First you need to get the correct ID for the job_template in question by calling in example

```bash
curl --silent -u "${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/ --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" | jq .results
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "job_template",
    "url": "/api/v2/job_templates/1/",
    "related": {
      "created_by": "/api/v2/users/1/",
      "modified_by": "/api/v2/users/1/",
      "labels": "/api/v2/job_templates/1/labels/",
      "inventory": "/api/v2/inventories/1/",
      "project": "/api/v2/projects/1/",
      "organization": "/api/v2/organizations/1/",
...
```

You may [filter it further jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq).

Then, with `ID='1'`, a `GET` call

```bash
curl --silent -u "${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" -X GET https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/${ID}/launch/ --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" | jq .
```

> *Make a `GET` request to this resource to determine if the `job_template` can be launched and whether any passwords are required to launch the `job_template` ...*

results into the correct information

```json
{
  "can_start_without_user_input": false,
  "passwords_needed_to_start": [],
  "ask_scm_branch_on_launch": false,
  "ask_variables_on_launch": false,
  "ask_tags_on_launch": false,
  "ask_diff_mode_on_launch": false,
  "ask_skip_tags_on_launch": false,
  "ask_job_type_on_launch": false,
  "ask_limit_on_launch": true,
  "ask_verbosity_on_launch": false,
  "ask_inventory_on_launch": false,
  "ask_credential_on_launch": true,
  "survey_enabled": false,
  "variables_needed_to_start": [],
  "credential_needed_to_start": false,
  "inventory_needed_to_start": false,
  "job_template_data": {
    "name": "Test",
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Test"
  },
  "defaults": {
    "extra_vars": "---\ntarget_hosts: test",
    "diff_mode": false,
    "limit": "test",
    "job_tags": "check",
    "skip_tags": "",
    "job_type": "run",
    "verbosity": 0,
    "inventory": {
      "name": "Inventory",
      "id": 1
    },
    "scm_branch": ""
  }
}
200
```

as well a `POST` call

```bash
curl --silent -u "${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" -X POST https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/job_templates/${ID}/launch/ --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" | jq .
```

> *Make a `POST` request to this resource to launch the `job_template`. If any passwords, inventory, or extra variables (extra_vars) are required, they must be passed via `POST` data, with `extra_vars` given as a YAML or JSON string and escaped parentheses ...*

with result

```json
{
  "job": 1,
  "ignored_fields": {},
  "id": 1,
  "type": "job",
  "url": "/api/v2/jobs/1/",
  ...
  "created": "2022-06-03T17:01:01.723657Z",
  "modified": "2022-06-03T17:01:01.779154Z",
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "job_type": "run",
  "inventory": 1,
  "project": 1,
...
}
201
```

**Documentation**

- [Ansible Tower REST API - Job Templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates)

Comment: I have the correct job_template Id taken from the URL, when you click on the job template. In addition to that, when i did a POST to api/user to create a user, it returned me the list of users instead of the creation of user, so it looked like that the POST in my ansible tower is overridden by the GET.

Also the response, that you had pasted for GET request, this is what i am getting in result of a POST request to launch job_template endpoint.

Comment: @saadbinsami, regarding "_the response, that you had pasted for `GET` request, this is what I am getting in result of a `POST` request to launch `job_template` endpoint_", as you can see from my example this isn't reproducible for me. Therefore it is recommended to provide debugging details, how do you construct the REST API calls together with the full JSON response by editing your question.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i was not calling the api, via the Https, instead i was calling it via Http(because the machine on which we have ansible installed is inside the network) protocol in postman, and this result in a weird response, i.e i was getting a GET response in request of a POST.

Comment: @saadbinsami this is why we usually ask for [Minimal complete and verifiable examples](/help/mcve) which you can provide at start for your next question (and might even solve the problem while you craft it and before you ask). You were not getting a weird response, simply a 302 redirect to your https endpoint and the redirect is made via GET.